# Is there a way to directly contact a user?

Tags: discussion, users

If I want to directly contact a user, instead of just commenting on a post of his, is there a way a can do that?

This could be useful, for instance, in providing guidance to a new user.

Comment: As a side note, if you would like to provide guidance for a new users, it should be left as a comment so *everyone* benefits from the advice.

Comment: You could add the tag `use-communication`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57203/private-messages-will-stackchat-reopen-the-debate) feature request on the Stack Exchange Network.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe contact this user by chat using `@username`. You can find more details on [that answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3294/129338).