# How do I pm a user of this website?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't AU allow users to privately communicate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3290/why-doesnt-au-allow-users-to-privately-communicate)

How do I send a private message to someone on this website? I want to ask them more questions about a certain command.

Comment: You could try to post a comment to one of his questions. Or check his profile for some other contact information.

Comment: You might also consider simply posting a new question on Ask Ubuntu, asking for the information you want to know. If this user is interested in the topic and sees the question, s/he might answer it! (And even if not, someone else might be able to.)

Comment: If you want to ask more question about a certain command, You can simply use Ask Ubuntu chat, or create a room for this topic only

Answer (score 4):

You don't. There is no PM functionality.

However you *can* earn the commenting privilege (just 50 rep) and then you can leave a comment on their answer. Or you can go through their profile and see if they've left any contact information.

Comment: @Sergiu: it is status by design and policy . Their reason is this is not a social network website

Comment: And ppl will leave contact information in their profile, If they are ready to handle pm, else just think that they are not ready for pm :)

Comment: @Sergiu ...And if they are not ready, You should not PM them