# Any reason to keep this feature request closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, meta

We should reopen this. It's just as constructive as any other feature request.

- [Feature request for "private messages" privilege for user communication](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3290/why-doesnt-au-allow-users-to-privately-communicate)

Wrongly closed (or wrongly open!) questions, on main or meta, are broken windows that mislead the whole community about what sorts of questions should and should not be closed. So even though this question is old, it's worth reopening.

While that meta question should never have been closed, the wording was harder to understand before [izx's edit](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/3290/revisions) (which happened before the question was closed but probably after a few of the close votes). Maybe that's why people voted to close it.

If you agree we should reopen it (and have something to add), or disagree and believe it should remain closed, or can explain what standards would justify closing that question without also closing the vast majority of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions on meta, please post an answer here!

Finally, a reminder relevant to the status of that meta question: It's considerably harder for a question to be *not constructive* on meta than to be *not constructive* on main. (Though it can happen.) On main, *discussion* is discouraged, and a question that calls for opinions is usually not constructive. In contrast, as [the meta FAQ](https://meta.askubuntu.com/faq) says:

> This site is for meta discussion about askubuntu.com.

Comment: Fully agree. Dicussions on meta should be left open as long as they are not entirely off, misleading or dupes. In this particular case it was probably closed [only because the OP asked us to do so](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3290/why-doesnt-au-allow-users-to-privately-communicate#comment4703_3291).

Comment: @Takkat At the time it seemed *closure* wasn't really what the OP wanted, but since the OP VTC'd it, maybe it was. Still, it's not really appropriate to close a feature request or discussion question under these circumstances, and anytime a question is closed because is obsolete or the OP no longer wants an answer, the *too localized* close reason should be used. Having this closed as *not constructive* teaches a wrong lesson about what that close reason means on meta. Still, if the OP affirms s/he wants it closed, I won't keep arguing for it to be reopened (unless it gets delete votes).

Comment: There's is a very small chance this will actually come true. SE has expressed no desire to do this in the past as there's really no need to have this feature. There's chat and comments already

Comment: @MarcoCeppi As I've said elsewhere, I agree we should not have the feature requested there. That's entirely irrelevant to the issues I've raised here, though. Closure is not how feature requests are declined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reopened the question. I think OP didn't actually want to close the question but maybe he misunderstood some of the jargon we use at that time.