# How to address a question to a particular user?

Tags: support, asking-questions, users, user-communication

Suppose I ask a question..I know that some user might be knowing its answer..

For eg,its a question related to a script.and i know that user xyz is good in scripts.I want him to notice my question..or rather I know he can answer..

By existing means,i can share a link to fb,twitter,email.But there is no option to share it with an ask ubuntu user itself.I dont know his e-id,m not on fb and twitter..or he isnt.

How can i do it?As of now i just add a comment with `@username` to let him know..any propper way to do it?

Comment: Might this be a feature request?

Answer (score 5):

I would tag the user in chat with `@username`.  Be patient - it can take a few hours if that user does not have that chatroom open.

A user is only notified when using `@username` in a question or answer if they have already contributed to that question or answer i.e. `@fredbloggs` will not work if fredbloggs had not previously added a comment or wasnt the original poster (OP).

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)