# Is there a way to send PM via Askubuntu?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't AU allow users to privately communicate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3290/why-doesnt-au-allow-users-to-privately-communicate)

Sometimes I would like to contact one Askubuntu user directly (for example to talk about a subject which is not directly related to Ubuntu).
Is there a way to send a message to somebody? (like PM in forums)

(sorry if the answer is obvious or already present somewhere-else)

Comment: I wonder if A private chatroom would serve this purpose?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/602/is-there-a-way-to-directly-contact-a-user

Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: We could close this as a duplicate of that question ([Is there a way to directly contact a user?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/602/is-there-a-way-to-directly-contact-a-user)), but I think it might be better to close this as a duplicate of [Why doesn't AU allow users to privately communicate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3290/why-doesnt-au-allow-users-to-privately-communicate) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Private chat rooms are one of the few methods, but only moderators can create truly private chat rooms, users if they have enough rep can create Gallery chat rooms, but those are logged publicly.

Other than that, there is no "private messaging" system on Ask Ubuntu.