# Contact Users seen on AskUbuntu

Tags: discussion

This question was asked in 2010 ([Is there a way to directly contact a user?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/602/is-there-a-way-to-directly-contact-a-user)), but I am hoping that the answer has changed. I am wanting to find some way to contact Ask Ubuntu users. Some users include an email address on their profile page, but some users do not. These are the users that I cannot contact. Has something changed where I can now contact them through StackExchange?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As maggotbrain mentions some users do not want to be contacted directly. They like their privacy and anonymity.

Because this fact is important, the SE network will not be publicly giving direct contact links from their users. This falls onto each user if he or she wishes to be open about it.

I for one do not mind and have helped many AU users via email, hangouts, skype or IRC solve problems that are strictly focused on Ubuntu. This is my decision and should not be used or be related to the way that maybe other moderators, Ask Ubuntu users or SE users feel or work like. They might also be doing the same thing or might not but again, this falls completely on the user and if he/she feels that wants to help in additional ways that Ask Ubuntu does not.

Note that in some cases, I end up linking the user answers that already exist in AU so using the Search option first is the best choice to start.

Answer (score 7):

Not every user of Ask Ubuntu wants to be contacted directly.

If their email address is in their profile, then I would expect that this would be the user giving implicit permission to be contacted.

However, many users give a great deal of support/hand-holding, here, and simply want to keep that support within the bounds of Ask Ubuntu.

Personally, I currently use an alias, but post a valid email address in my profile. I wouldn't mind if someone got in touch with me directly; but, I also don't want the support that I may provide here, spilling over outside of Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

No, the answer has not changed. The only way to contact users is through information they provide on their profile pages. You can *sometimes* contact a user in the SE chat, but they must have visited chat in the last three days to get your ping.

Answer (score 1):

Some users, [like me](https://askubuntu.com/users/134848/jop), provide an e-mail address in their profile that you can use to contact them.