# How do I reply to a user who tagged me in a comment?

Tags: discussion, user-communication

I've seen that there's no such feature as a pm system as stated on the answer to [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/602/is-there-a-way-to-directly-contact-a-user) and I perfectly understand why;

The problem is that a new user has no way of replying to inbox since:

1. he/she can't post comments until obtaining 50 reputation ( and it
   would be unadvisable to reply there, because it would just clutter up a space reserved to useful comments );
2. he/she can't use chat either since it has some other reputation requirement.

I sincerely can't understand this last point, and I'm not referring to the inability to contact a user first ( because that would open up the ground for spammers ), but rather to the disallowance on replying to an inbox.

I think his particular aspect might be something worth looking into and that there's room for a new useful feature.

Sorry for the somewhat muddled bits of this post.

Comment: You can still "ping" anyone involved in your questions and answers directly! Try this out with @Fabby by adding a comment here below

Comment: What are you referring to when you say, "inbox"?

Comment: @Fabby yes, I can do that in my questions, however I still can't on other users' questions _if I was mentioned_  (and that's the only eventuality in which it would be helpful to add this "can reply" feature... not that it's extremely important, but still)
Btw I just wanted to reply you :P :D ; I just wanted to say something in my defence :D,  that I suggested an edit of that question nearly at the same time it was put on hold, but I can perfectly see why you wrote that advice: the time of my edit shown by the system is for when it has been effectively approved, not when it was first suggested.

Comment: @RolandiXor I'm referring to the top left area: first button on the right of the StackExchange banner

Comment: @RolandiXor: he probably means [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dHkq0.png)?

Comment: @RookieGui: :D  No worries!  The first 50 rep are hardest to get.  Once you're there it'll be easier...  Just keep up the good work!!! **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

Even before you earn [the "Comment everywhere" privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment), you should be able to comment...

- Under any of your answers, and
- Anywhere in your questions (ie under your question, or under its answers)

To me, that covers every eventuality where you might want to reply. People aren't going to be mentioning you unless you've already posted something...

Am I reading this wrong? Where were you mentioned that you cannot reply?

Comment: Just for reference [this is the comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645620/17-2-and-the-problems-installing-wine#comment925735_645620) where I was mentioned.  
I think it's a good example for a rare use case in which I'd want to reply but I can't  
( since I acknowledge it's rare, it might be out of question spending some time to add this feature just to cover up this unlikely eventuality, but it's still within realm of possibility  ).